# Any syntax highlighting for CL interpreters?

Tags: linux, shell, syntax-highlighting, interpreter

When invoking 'python' or 'guile' or any other interpreter, I like the read-eval-print interface, but I miss syntax highlighting, paren-matching, and quick navigation like within vim.  Are there any programs that provide a more ergonomic interface to shells / interpreters?

Answer (score 0):

For python have a look at [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/), it supports inline syntax highlighting and parent-matching. OTOH [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) is also quite useful, for example you can just write help $function and it will run help($function) automatically.